# Quick explanation of $\Gamma \tau$ notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I hope you can help me by quickly explaining the following notation: $\Gamma \tau$. This notation is encountered in A First Course in Modular Forms by Fred Diamond and Jerry Shurman (love the book by the way). A modular curve is introduced as $Y(\Gamma) = \Gamma \backslash \mathcal{H} = \{ \Gamma \tau : \tau \in \mathcal{H} \}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is the complex upper half plane. $\Gamma$ is a congruence subgroup of the modular group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. So what does $\Gamma \tau$ mean? Does it mean *all* the elements $\gamma \tau$ with $\gamma \in \Gamma$, i.e., $\Gamma \tau = \{\gamma \tau : \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ for some fixed $\tau$?

I hope you can help me clarify this. It seems to be a very central concept. ;)

Thanks!

Comment: I'd assume they mean the (right) [coset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset) of $\Gamma$ with respect to $\tau$, which has the meaning you suspected. So $Y(\Gamma)$ is the set of all such cosets generated by elements of the upper half plane.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure, @Semiclassical? $\tau$ is not an element of the group here. We have a group $\Gamma$ acting on a set $\mathcal{H}$, and $\tau\in\mathcal{H}$. It feels very natural to assume that $\Gamma\tau$ is the orbit of $\tau$ under the action of $\Gamma$. This is consistent with the notation $\Gamma\mathcal{H}$ meaning the set of orbits.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So say $\Gamma = \{\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \ldots, \gamma_n\}$. Then $\Gamma \tau$, being the orbit of $\tau$ under the action of $\Gamma$, is $\{\gamma_1 \tau, \gamma_2 \tau, \ldots, \gamma_n \tau\}$, right?

Comment: Bo, that's the idea! Except that your $\Gamma$ has infnitely many elements, so I would be a bit hesitant writing it as a finite list such as $\{\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n\}$ - here $n=\infty$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yep, just wanted to illustrate how I understood it. :) Thanks Jyrki!!

Comment: YW. The quotient space (orbit space?) $\Gamma\backslash\mathcal{H}$ is modelled as such a subset, a fundamental domain, of the upper half-plane that contains exactly one point from each orbit. The best known case is when $\Gamma$ is all of $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$, and the fundamental domain consists of the points $z$ with absolute value $\ge1$ and the absolute value of the real part $\le1/2$ (with some conventions to deal with borders). With other groups the fundamental domain is more complicated, but the idea of it intersecting each orbit at a single point stays.